# How to create a Person object by splitting a string

Tags: java

I have to split a string (John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow) using `split` method(" ");
I think I should use a `for` loop to obtain the values corresponding to the field of the `Person` class, but how do I do that and how do I create a `Person` object and add it to an object list?
I've done this:

```
    String[] peopleArray = warehouse.split(" ");
    String[][] personArray = new String[peopleArray.length][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++) {
        personArray[i] = peopleArray[i].split("/|\\.");
        
        for (String field : personArray[i]) {
            
            System.out.print(field + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
```

I can't get the fields with this method

Person class is created with the name, lastname, date of birth , and place of birth, fields.

This is my Person Class

```
package warehouse;
```

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Person {

```
public String name;

public String lastname;

public LocalDate dateOfBirth;

public String placeOfBirth;

DateTimeFormatter FORM = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMM yyyy.");


public Person(String name, String lastname, LocalDate dateOfBirth, String placeOfBirth) {

    this.name = name;

    this.lastname = lastname;

    this.placeOfBirth = placeOfBirth;

    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getPlaceOfBirth() {
    return placeOfBirth;
}

public void setPlaceOfBirth(String placeOfBirth) {
    this.placeOfBirth = placeOfBirth;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return dateOfBirth.format(FORM);
}

public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
@Override

public String toString() {

    return ("Name: " + name + " ; " + "Lastname: " + lastname + " ; " + "Date of birth: " + dateOfBirth.format(FORM) + " ; "
            + "Place of birth: " + placeOfBirth);

}
```

}

Comment: You have to write a mapper for string array to person object conversion on set person field on respect on position

Comment: create Person POJO class. also create name setter and getter for this POJO. then in your array has  elements after splitting based on */*. so u have person name in [0]th index. after getting 0th index, you can set that name into setter method.after set, you can add into list if needed

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: @R.Wang 
John Davidson 05082004 Belgrade  
Michael Barton 01011998 Krakov  
Ivan Perkinson 23051986 Moscow

Comment: @SathishKumarJ cant use setter, it says i cant use a String[] as String, or something like that

Comment: Do you do this for exercise? If not, use a standardized data exchange format like JSON. Splitting strings can involve a lot of guesswork or result in the negotiation of custom rules for formatting / escaping. Example: A Person with 2 first names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, ParseException {
    String warehouse = "John.Davidson/05082004/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011998/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
    String[] peopleArray = warehouse.split(" ");
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++) {
        String[] person = peopleArray[i].split("/|\\.");
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy"); // first example
        Date d1 = format1.parse(person[2]);
        persons.add(new Person(person[0], person[1], d1, person[3]));
    }
}
```

This may work for below person class:

```
static class Person {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    Date date;
    String place;

    public Person(String name, String lastName, Date date, String place) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.date = date;
        this.place = place;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i adapted it to what i have, and worked like a charm.